# How do I make the scrollview force scroll down in python tkinter?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

so I have created a vertical scrollview in tkinter in a frame in python, however I want that scroll view to always scroll down. Is there any way I can make that scroll view to scroll down, are there any commands and if there are how do I do it

```
scroll_x = Scrollbar(ShowDataFrame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(ShowDataFrame,orient=VERTICAL)




chattable = Treeview(ShowDataFrame,columns=('name','chat'),yscrollcommand=scroll_y,xscrollcommand=scroll_x)
scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scroll_x.config(command=chattable.xview)
scroll_y.config(command=chattable.yview)
```

How do I make the scroll_y force scroll downwards?

Comment: `.yview` and `.xview` are those functions, that is exactly what the scrollbars use, you can use it too, also it should be `yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set` and the same for `x`

Comment: oh yeah mistake by my side, however do you know how to force the scrollbar down, supposing you made a table in tkinter and you want always the recent column to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an item to be visible and you know the id, you can use the `see` method of the treeview widget.

For example, if you know that the last item has an id of "I064" you can scroll it into view like this:

```
chattable.see("I064")
```

If you don't have the id and simply want to scroll, you can scroll the widget by calling one of the `yview` methods (`yview`, `yview_moveto`, `yview_scroll`).

For example, to scroll to the end you can use `yview_moveto` with the value `1.0`. The number represents what fraction of the contents should be scrolled off of the top. A value of `.5` would scroll half-way through the data, a value of `0` scrolls to the top, and `1` scrolls to the bottom.

```
chattable.yview_moveto(1.0)
```